# Est-ce qu’il existe un problème relevant de la reprise de l’information dans la phrase ci-après?

Tags: formulation, reformulation, pronom-de-reprise

Phrase en question:

> Est-ce qu’il existe un terme proche du mot concerné qui pourrait le remplacer pour porter la phrase à un registre supérieur?

En fait, c’est le référent de « le » dans la phrase qui me laisse hésitant (j’ai à l’idée que « le » pourrait renvoyer à « terme proche »). Je suis conscient que cette possibilité devrait logiquement être écartée si on s’en rapporte au contexte, mais d’un point vue grammatical, la phrase serait-elle défectueuse? Un correcteur aguerri relèverait-il  dans ce cas-ci une erreur liée à la reprise de l’information?

Est-ce qu’il serait préférable que je reformule la phrase en question ainsi:

> Est-ce qu’il existe un terme proche qui pourrait remplacer le mot concerné pour porter la phrase à un registre supérieur?

Comment: @LPH Il n'y a pas lieu de corriger l'absence d'espace devant un point d'interrogation quand le texte suit les usages québécois.

Comment: @jean-Lou Frenette  Vous auriez dû me signaler que la ponctuation est celle du québécois ;  je ne pensais pas qu'il y ait une différence. En fait, user Eyla Chu Generis, qui est un québécois utilise la ponctuation française ; cela rend les choses compliquées…

Comment: @LPH Je n’en doute pas, les prochaines fois je tâcherai d’employer la ponctuation française pour rendre plus simple la tâche des contributeurs.

Comment: Non, vous ne devriez pas faire ça ; que l'on sache que vous tenez à préserver les pratiques enseignées au Québec est tout ce qui importe. On ne devrait pas vous forcer à des mélanges  qui ne correspondent pas à vos préférences actuelles.

Comment: Bien reçu LPH! Je vous remercie pour le retour d’information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Est-ce qu’il existe un terme proche **du mot concerné** qui pourrait le remplacer pour porter la phrase à un registre supérieur ?

Dans tous les cas, ce n'est qu'une question de style et moins le style laisse au lecteur à déduire implicitement, le plus pur il est, mais il y a certaines limites et on admet la déduction implicite dans certaines limites comme pratique courante. De plus, rien ne dicte du point de vue de la grammaire comment choisir le référent. Il n'y a donc pas de faute de grammaire puisque « terme » et « mot » sont tous les deux masculins. Si le sens n'était pas clair du tout on pourrait seulement dire que la formulation est ambigüe.

Dans la première phrase, il est clair que l'existence d'un terme est sujette à la possibilité qu'il puisse remplacer quelque chose ; en toute logique il ne peut remplacer que quelque chose autre que lui même. Même si le domaine n'est pas la linguistique, on ne conçoit rien qui ait une capacité de remplacement de soi-même.

*Prenons les exemples suivants.*

- (a) Elle allait lui acheter un château en papier-mâché  pour son anniversaire ; elle ne **l**'avait pas oublié. (*Le référent est « elle allait acheter … »*)
- (b) Elle allait lui acheter un château en papier-mâché  pour son anniversaire ; elle se **le** représentait déjà, grand, avec de nombreuses tours et un beau donjon tout vert. (*Le référent est « château » ; noter qu'à la lecture du mot « grand », on ne peut qu'éliminer le référent précédent et que l'on ne sait toujours pas certainement ce que « le » remplace ; ce n'est qu'à la lecture du syntagme prépositionnel qui suit que l'on sait qu'il s'agit de « château », parce qu'il n'y a que le château dans ce contexte qui puisse avoir des tours.*)
- (c)  Elle allait lui acheter un vélo pour son anniversaire ; elle ne **l**'avait jamais oublié depuis qu'il avait six ans, jusqu'à aujourd'hui, où il allait en avoir dix-huit. (*On arrive, mais pas d'une façon si immédiate, à déterminer que le référent est « anniversaire », et le style est peu enviable.*)

On voit donc que la détermination du référent est une question de contexte et peu une affaire de grammaire (différence entre « le » et « la »).

Il n'existe pas relativement à la phrase qui est investiguée de critère autre que ceux qui sont applicables dans les exemples ci-dessus ((a), (b)). Elle n'est donc pas plus mauvaise du point de vue style.

---

> Est-ce qu’il existe un terme proche qui pourrait remplacer le mot concerné pour porter la phrase à un registre supérieur?

La phrase proposée en tant qu'alternative plus « correcte » élimine radicalement cette impression parasitique de référent ambigu, qui n'est peut-être que l'impression d'un esprit pas suffisamment rompu à la logique des choses, et l'on s'engage alors dans une discussion sans fin dans le sens de déterminer quel niveau de difficulté on doit tolérer dans la déductibilité logique des éléments qui sont agencés par la phrase ; on doit reconnaitre que l'on ne trouve pas dans les exemples utilisés ci-dessus le moindre sujet à proscription, alors pourquoi en trouver dans la phrase investiguée ?

On peut reprocher à cette alternative de laisser l'idée de proximité en ballant, mais encore une fois, la logique veut qu'il s'agisse de la proximité au mot concerné, ce qui devient inéluctable à la lecture entière de la phrase. Donc, cette formulation alternative est aussi valable, à mon avis.

Answer (score 0):

Voici une façon de résoudre ce problème de référence:

> Est-ce qu’il existe un terme proche du mot concerné **et** qui pourrait remplacer **ce dernier** pour porter la phrase à un registre supérieur ?

Comment: À en juger par ta réponse, il y avait bien un problème de référence! Je te remercie au nom de toute la communauté « French Stack Exchange » pour l’effort constant que tu déploies sur cette plateforme de questions et de réponses.

Comment: Il n'y avait pas foncièrement de problème de référence, seulement une hypothétique ambiguïté. La compréhension est néanmoins facilitée en rendant explicite l'antécédent.